# about Spring3 MVC Controller's @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Can't one RequestMapping name,such as `@RequestMapping("/console")`, be used in several class? I mean Controller's class mapping. BTW, method's requestmapping will be diferent.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I recommend that you *don't* do what you're trying to do as it can be difficult to maintain. In my opinion, organisation of URLs / mappings is important in the same way you organise your code.

The documentation [@RequestMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) suggests the same:

> It is strongly recommended to co-locate related handler methods into the same bean.

But regarding your question - I don't believe that this is possible. Again, from the documentation of @RequestMapping (emphasis is my own):

> **Method-level mappings** are only allowed to *narrow* the mapping expressed at the **class level** (if any). HTTP paths / portlet modes need to **uniquely map onto specific handler beans**, with any given path / mode only allowed to be mapped onto one specific handler bean (not spread across multiple handler beans).